# Oro localization switcher based on URL

Tags: orocrm, orocommerce

I need to configure website for difference languages based by path.
Example:
`my.site/en/` and `my.site/fr/` stands for `en` and `fr` localizations. I know it's possible to do with the help of multi-website configuration. Is it possible to do with only one website? In this case our users would have access to all localizations with one auth.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the application in a subfolder to have locales in the URL:
https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/setup/installation-in-sub-folder/.